# how to preserve the jquery mobile styles when dynamically populating listview

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on jquery mobile. Currently i am using jquery.mobile.1.0.1 version js and css. I have jquery mobile listview with prefilled data like,

```
<ul id="ulstorelist" data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d">
<li>Items ToDay</li>
.
.
<li>Item Week</li>
.
.
<li>Item month</li>
.
.
<li>Item 4</li>
.
.
</ul>
```

i need to filter the above listview with different search criterias like user can filter by today,this week,month etc. so that i decided to make use of jquery ajax calls to get the data from my action(MVC) and generate list and then append to parent ul listview like,

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnToday').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/FieldVisit/GetTodaystores',
                data: {},
                type: 'get',
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (k, v) {

                        var g = "<li <a href='#'>>" +
                                "<h3>" + v.CompanyName + "</h3>" +
                                "</a></li>";
                        $("#ulstorelist").append(g);
                        $("#ulstorelist").listview('refresh');
                        $("#ulstorelist").trigger('create');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
});
```

but the jquery mobile styles all are vanished. but when i write inline style to li its working fine but i need jquery mobile styles. how to preserve the jquery mobile styles when generating listview items dynamically. please guide me.

Comment: Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready() http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: remove this $("#ulstorelist").trigger('create'); this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This might be your problem:

```
var g = "<li <a href='#'>>" +
```

... it should probably be:

```
var g = "<li><a href='#'>" +
```

Its not uncommon for invalid HTML to cause all kinds of layout problems.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try calling $("#ulstorelist").listview('refresh'); after the $each loop.  I'm not sure if calling it before triggering create might be an issue.